# Is there a way to create a text field with a prefix that is always visible in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a text field with a prefix that is always visible. I am creating a phone field similar to the one used for WhatsApp phone number entry. I would like to have the country code as a persistent prefix.

I have tried the prefix and prefixText options for InputDecoration, however, the prefixes are only visible when the textField is in focus. Any help offered on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19488) that was closed with solution:

> Closing for now as it's not possible to keep the prefix text visible
>   in all states with a floating placeholder which is the main usage of
>   this widget.

And some workaround that worked for me:

```
TextStyle _decorationStyleOf(BuildContext context) {
  final theme = Theme.of(context);
  return theme.textTheme.subhead
      .copyWith(color: theme.hintColor);
}

Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  children: <Widget>[
    Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Text(
          'prefix',
          style: _decorationStyleOf(context),
        );
      }
    ),
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixText: 'prefix',
        prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. It only makes the prefixText completely transparent.

Comment: **NEW UPDATE!!! CHECK MY ANSWER BELOW. You only need to change the properties of `InputDecoration`.**

Answer (score 90):

**UPDATE: We can now override the minimum padding of `prefixIcon` AND `suffixIcon` with `prefixIconConstraints`.**

We can use `prefixIcon` instead of `prefixText`. Since `prefixIcon` accepts any widget, we can use `prefixIcon: Text("$")`.

Here is an example:

```
InputDecoration(
   isDense: true,
   prefixIcon:Text("\$"),
   prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, minHeight: 0),
),
```

Comment: if you add `labelText` the line breaks

Comment: you probably need it like this `Text("\$")` else it throws error

Comment: @MDompekidis Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice that. I've changed the answer.

Comment: @Uni Perfect. Solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: There is just one problem with the answer. I need to use `prefixIcon` and `prefixText` both at same time. At the time `prefixIcon` stays visible after focus change but `prefixText` isn't. I want both of them to be visible.

Answer (score 40):

This is the perfect solution that worked when I have to display the prefix always visible

```
prefixIcon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(15), child: Text('+91 ')),
```

Comment: Using prefixIcon instead of prefix worked, thanks for the ans.

Answer (score 5):

```
FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();


@override
  void dispose() {

    focusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
```

inside build write

```
hintText = prefix;


focusNode.addListener(() {
  if (focusNode.hasFocus) {

    setState(() {
      hintText = '';
      hasHint = false;
    });

  }
  else {

    setState(() {
      hintText = prefix;
      hasHint = true;
    });

  }

});
```

Inside InputDecoration, do this:

```
 InputDecoration(

      border: InputBorder.none,
      errorMaxLines: 1,          
      prefixText: hasHint ? '' : prefix,
      prefixStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black54
      ),
      hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
      hintText: hasHint ? prefix : '',
      hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
          color: Colors.black54
      ),
    ),
```

wherein prefix variable is whatever you want to be the prefix. Please vote up this answer if it solves your issue. dubace's answer only made my prefixText go completely transparent.

This puts in a hint that takes the place of the prefixText when textField has not be focused on. When it is focused then the prefixText shows up and the hint disappears.Inside textField, consider putting an ontap method wherein you set the state so that the hint goes away and the prefix shows up. Because in some situation, when the textfield is tapped, the system still does not understand that is has focus unless something is actually typed.

Answer (score 3):

The prefixIcon work around did not work for me, as my input is multiline. After reaching two lines, the icon centers instead of staying aligned with the first line as true prefix text should.

As such I discovered [CrossAxisAlignment.textBaseline](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html), which allows one to simply attach a prefix widget using a Row as follows:

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
    children: [Text("prefix: "), inputWidget]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you define an initial value in the TextField controller can also resolve this issue.
Since TextField will own content, causing the prefix to appear.

Like so:

```
TextEditingController currencyField = TextEditingController(text: '0,00');

TextFormField(
  autofocus: false,
  controller: currencyField,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
    hintText: '0,00',
    prefixText: '\$ ',
    labelText: 'Price',
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
  ),
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
    CurrencyFormatter(), // My currency formatter
  ],
  enableSuggestions: true,
  enableInteractiveSelection: true,
  toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
    copy: true,
    cut: true,
    paste: true,
    selectAll: true,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use PrefixIcon instead Prefix, coz prefix alone will appears after the prefixIcon, if both are specified and try to override prefixIconConstraints to be with Zero padding and margin.
for example :

```
 decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: PhoneCode(),
                      prefixIconConstraints:
                          BoxConstraints(),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

A work around this for me was (used as textfield prefixIcon)

```
return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          '${m4eWalletProvider.wallet.walletInfo.currency.toString()} ',
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `prefixIcon` or `suffixIcon` attribute of the InputDecoration instead of the `prefixText` or `suffixText`.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the prefix text active even when the textformfield is not in focus in a way by using prefixIcon instead of prefixText :

for example:

```
prefixIcon: Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12,10, 4, 5), 
  child: Text('+91 ')
),
```

in place of

```
prefixText: ("+91")
```

Comment: I believe your left, right, top & bottom padding is not accurate & correct.

Comment: I believe your left, right, top & bottom padding is not accurate & correct.

Comment: Yes, it was a random number that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it like this:
Use  suffix Icon property to make the suffix icon always visible regardless of focused or unfocused

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can try use prefixIcon prop then combine with Align

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Text('\$'),
```