# how to use uncompleted url in plugin InAppWebView for browsing in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

if I input link: youtube.com, `URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(url))` will not response this url, so I have to input https://www.youtube.com/, but normal user will not input so complicated url link, so is that a way to let InAppWebView confirm this uncompleted url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around:

1. In the Input field use a prefix text as "https://" and get the URL from the user. In this way the user would know to not type the HTTP part again. ( like the dollar symbol in the below image)
2. Edit this line to: `URLRequest("https://"+url: Uri.parse("https://"+url))`

[image]

How to add prefix text to input field? [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819979/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-text-field-with-a-prefix-that-is-always-visible-in-fl)

Comment: Dear Nagulan, thank you for your answer, it indeed helps me