# Custom stylig CountryCodePicker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I want this type of `country_code_picker` styling, but can't adjust the `width` and `height` of [country_code_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/country_code_picker)

[image]

Here is my code

```
InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Nationality',
                labelStyle:
                    const TextStyle(color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      const BorderSide(color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: CountryCodePicker(
                initialSelection: 'AE',
                showCountryOnly: true,
                textOverflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: true,
                showDropDownButton: true,
              ),
            ),
```

My Output

[image]

How can I make this looks like above style?

Comment: Use [floatingLabelBehavior.always](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/floatingLabelBehavior.html)

Comment: What will be the UI on selected mode

Comment: I'm designing filter page where I want a nationality filed , user  can get the nationality from this drop down menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Stack and `CountryCodePicker`'s builder .

```dart
body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => Center(
    child: Container(
      width: constraints.maxWidth,
      height: 64,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24))),
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: -10,
            left: 24,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8),
              color: Colors.white,
              // container can be replace with text filed color
              child: Text(
                "Language",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: constraints.maxWidth,
            height: 64,
            child: CountryCodePicker(
              builder: (p0) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 25,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      if (p0?.code != null) Text(p0!.code!),
                      // decorate others 
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              showCountryOnly: true,
              showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: true,
              showDropDownButton: true,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

### modify some decoration and it will be perfect.

You can use `prefix` instead of `prefixIcon`. The issue will it won’t be visible always. For this, you can use `autofocus: true,` on TextFiled, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58819979/10157127) about prefix visibility.

```dart
 TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            decoration:  InputDecoration(
      isDense: true,
      prefix: CountryCodePicker(
        showCountryOnly: true,
        showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: true,
        showDropDownButton: true,
      ),
      label: Text('Language'),
      floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.start,
      floatingLabelBehavior:  
          ),
```

You can also wrap `CountryCodePicker` with Sizedbox for sizing.

Comment: it open also keypad. I want only show dropdown menu.

Comment: try readOnly:true also I think you can use other approach instead of TextFormFiled in this case.

Comment: Hi, I've changed my approach and updated my question. Please take a look now.

Comment: you can wrap CountryCodePicker with Sizedbox for sizing.

Comment: I tried but couldn't adjust