# Best way to change a standard flutter widget

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

In my app I would like to make the `suffixText` property of the `InputDecoration` of a `TextFormField` always visible (not just when the field is not empty or when it is focused). I took a look at the flutter code and it is a 1-line change on the `input_decorator.dart` file. This file is used by `text_field.dart` which is used by `text_form_field.dart`. Of course I know that I could copy-paste all that 3 files in my project with my 1-line change. But is this the best option? There are several drawbacks:

- If the flutter team updates those files (e.g. because of a bug), I have to patch them manually every time by copy-pasting
- I have to add 6k lines of code to my project
- I'm not sure if I can even copy-paste that code to my project because of the terms of the license

All of this for a 1-line change. Please tell me that there are better way of achieving this result. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the highest score answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819979/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-text-field-with-a-prefix-that-is-always-visible-in-fl), you can do something like this to have a permanent suffix, I've tried on DartPad and it works:

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Text('permanent suffix'),
    suffixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 0, minHeight: 0),
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you, I marked this question as the solution because solves my problem. Even if I would like to know what should we do in this kind of situation when there are no workaround

Comment: You are welcome. In general I don't think it is a good solution to copy and override parts of Flutter 
 code, for the reasons you mentioned. You can create your own custom widgets from existing building blocks but it can be a lot of work if what you need is not supported.