# Is there a way i can add a text next to the input value of text editing controller in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, widget, textfield, textformfield

Is there a way I can add `RichText()` with the input value of `TextFormField` in flutter?
For example
I want to show 5000rs in `TextFormField`. How can I add rs with the input value?

I used a row widget and add two children a `TextField` and a text widget to achieve this.
I disable all the borders of the text field.
but it gives me output as 5000  rs. it does not go with my UI as I need 5000rs in `TextField`.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to create a text field with a prefix that is always visible in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819979/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-text-field-with-a-prefix-that-is-always-visible-in-fl)

Comment: Explore InputDecoration of TextFormField. You will surely find your solution there.